# Use dynamic number of backreferences

Tags: regex, backreference

Is there a way to loop through all backreferences in a regex replace scenario? To better understand what I am asking for:

Given you have the following text

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
```

When you have a regex that matches an arbitrary number of items like

```
(([\w \d]+),?)*
```

Then you want the result to be something along the lines

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I'm searching for the right pattern in the **Replace with** field e.g. in notepad++ or whatever editor that supports extended regex stuff:
[image]

Is that even possible?

Comment: Place the `<ul>` manually, the rest is trivial. What you want here is the job of a templating engine. Regex is not complex enough to do this, I'm afraid (_and it's too complex already, as is_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a single replacement, no. However, you could do it using multiple replacements.

If you search for the regex `([^,]+),?` and replace with `<li>\1</li>` (or maybe `<li>$1</li>`. I'm not familiar with how N++'s regex engine works) it will replace each of your list items with an HTML list item.

All you need to do after that is put `<ul>` tags around the result.